# Google Drive Service: "Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Google_DriveService::__construct() must be an instance of Google_Client"

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-client

So yeah, the error just makes it look like the argument isn't an instance of the Google Drive Service. I've looked up and down for people with similar errors but I've got nothing. Here's the full error and then my code:

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Google_DriveService::__construct() must be an instance of Google_Client, none given, called in php-google-oauth/data2.php on line 23 and defined in php-google-oauth/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php on line 1041

Google_DriveService.php (around line 1041):

```
class Google_DriveService extends Google_Service {
  public $about;
  public $apps;
  public $changes;
  public $children;
  public $comments;
  public $files;
  public $parents;
  public $permissions;
  public $replies;
  public $revisions;
  /**
    * Constructs the internal representation of the Drive service.
    *
    * @param Google_Client $client
  */
  public function __construct(Google_Client $client) { //LINE 1021
  $this->servicePath = 'drive/v2/';
  $this->version = 'v2';
  $this->serviceName = 'drive';
  // ....
```

data2.php:

```
// ..... (defining GDRIVE_...s)
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId( GDRIVE_CLIENT_ID );
$client->setClientSecret( GDRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET );
$client->setRedirectUri( GDRIVE_REDIRECT_URIS );
$client->setScopes( array( GDRIVE_SCOPE_01, GDRIVE_SCOPE_02, GDRIVE_SCOPE_03, GDRIVE_SCOPE_04, GDRIVE_SCOPE_05 ) );
$service = new Google_DriveService(); // LINE 23
// ....
```

I'm calling the `Google_Client()` class instance BEFORE I call the Drive service... So I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Argument 1 passed to Google_DriveService::__construct() must be an instance of Google_Client, none given

This means that you must pass (at least) one argument when instantiating `Google_DriveService` and that the argument you pass must be an instance of the `Google_Client` class.

Instead of this:

```
$service = new Google_DriveService();
```

You need:

```
$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
```

Comment: Don't feel stupid. Just make sure that you know what the `__construct` method is (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) and it's helpful to know how it's able to require a specific type of class (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)